# Airflow: how to re-run dependent DAGs

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, airflow

Suppose I have following DAG dependencies:

```
        /> DAG B -->....
       /
      /
DAG A ---> DAG C -->...
      \
       \
        \> DAG D -->...
```

These DAGs are running daily, and output of DAG A is consumed by DAG B,C,D respectively.

If the DAG A failed (e.g. Spark job had a bug and we want to re-execute it after the fix), how to make sure we also re-run DAGs B,C,D etc so that now they run with fixed DAG A output ? Can it be done automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a separate **Main DAG** (**controller_dag**) and use **[TriggerDagRunOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator/index.html)** to trigger different DAGs.

The dependencies between tasks using **TriggerDagRunOperator** can be set in the following way:

```py
dag_a >> [dag_b, dag_c, dag_d] >> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use TriggerDagRunOperator for this purpose
  https://www.astronomer.io/guides/trigger-dag-operator/
- You can also consider consolidating these DAGs into a single DAG using SubDAGOperator. In this case, Sub-DAGs b,c,d can depend on Sub-DAG a.